# JHipster - How to add route to external microservices in application.yml

Tags: microservices, jhipster, netflix-zuul

I'm using Jhipster 5.5.0 to build a zuul gateway capable to route rest request to  different microservices. 
Some of this microservices are developed in different languages, deployed and running on different server. Every microservices is protected via OIDC using the same keycloak server, under different realms.

Now I need to configure zuul route on application.yml properties file of my gateway app, to access this service by external rest client (customers) and using zuul for filtering request and keycloak as oidc token provider.
Then I modify gateway application.yml adding the following zuul route to a sample external service (this type of configuration work well with another zuul gateway developed for another project without using jhipster):

```
    # zuul routing:
    zuul:
      ignored-services: "*"
      routes:
        # external endpoints
        myapi-v2-test:
          path: /my-api/mypackage/v2/add
          sensitiveHeaders: Cookie, Set-Cookie
          url: http://192.168.3.148:8080/server/rest/api/mypackage_2.0.0/add
```

When I try to test the call using a soap-ui client with Auth Bearer token in header, provided by the keycloak server using the jhipster realm (and client_id "web_app"), I always receive  the response error code `403 - Forbidden` for  path 
"/my-api/mypackage/v2/add". 
What is the right way to configure the application.yml of the gateway app?

Thank in advance for any help.

**I'm not using registry service (e.g Spring Cloud Eureka or Jhipster Registry)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my solution in case someone have the same question. To solve my problem I added in `OAuth2SsoConfiguration.java` this line of code in **configure(WebSecurity web)** method:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .
            .antMatchers("/my-api/**")
            .
    }
```

and the following in **configure(HttpSecurity http)**:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .
        .
    .and()
        .
        .antMatchers("/my-api/**").permitAll()
        .
        .
}
```